# How to show a svg image into Image control?

Tags: c#

I stay using wpf and I need to show this image:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Eintracht_Frankfurt_Logo.svg

into my Image control.

How can I handle a web request that allows me to upload images into the control? Can anyone show me this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the open source project from codeplex to convert svg into XAML:
http://svg2xaml.codeplex.com/

Then you can load your SVG like this:

```
using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  DrawingImage image = SvgReader.Load(stream);

  // SvgReaderOptions options = new SvgReaderOptions(...);
  // DrawingImage image = SvgReader.Load(stream, options);
}
```

Comment: there is no way to perform it without use external library?

Comment: Not sure. You can probably render SVG in WebBrowser control as SVG can be opened in browser but it's even more heavy whereas the lib I mentioned doesn't have external dependencies so it's like light solution.